# Cant get value from ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im using this account because im logged in on facebook on my other and i dont have my phone with me to do the pass code verification ect..

Anyway.. Im trying to get the value from a ng-model but i just cannot seem to get it no matter what i try. I think i need some other eyes to have a quick look at my code to see if they can work it out, Cheers...

```
Html:


<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Established :</label>
<div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="established"></div>
</div>                        

<button class="btn btn-primary " style="float:right;" ng-click="saveApprisalDetails()" type="button"><i class="fa fa-paste"></i> Save</button>


Controller:

        $scope.saveApprisalDetails=function(){
    var urlgetappraisals = './dbscripts/getAppraisalsByRef.php?ref=' + ref
    console.log(urlgetappraisals);
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: urlgetappraisals
    }).success(function(data) {

        $scope.appraisaldetails = data;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

    var url = './dbscripts/saveApprisal.php?id=' + data[0].id;
        url += '&appraisalCompany=' + appraisalCompany;
        url += '&title=' + ref;
        url += '&established=' + $scope.established;

 console.log(url);

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url
            }).success(function(data) {
            })
    })
}
}
catch(e){}
}
```

Comment: Is the controller connected successfull? Press F12 what does the debugger say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something different to see if it works, in the begginning of the controller:

```
$scope.view_data = {};
```

In the function:

```
url += '&established=' + $scope.vies_data.established;
```

And in the view:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="view_data.established">
```

Hope it helps =)